# Asp.net odbcCommand not closing connection to mySql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, odbc

**Hi everyone,**

i share my pics and my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnnBK.jpg

I have a loop (pic2) in which i need read the some data link to my id....

However... the function works but during longer loops after a while it return as too many connection; in clients connection page (pic1) i saw that the previous query weren't disposed but i think my code (pic 3-4) is correct...

my co-worker suggested me to read it in one query through inner join, but i prefer to find another way for 2 reason:

- my way of code is to make a query and load the records as custom class in a list and i would have to navigate directly in datatable and it'll be messy
  -i have to read external data for a lot of field and one-shot query will be messy and hard to manage for other people

**any idea? thk for reading**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God that's old school =) You're not closing the data reader. Also please use `using` to avoid this eye sore. You can find a textbook example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 .

Comment: Yeah... The classes are old (before using existed), but i didn't knew that could be such a problem